# Emacs: What does it mean to 'put a caret on a word'?

Tags: r, emacs

I am trying to utilize the ess-R-data-view.el package to view data frames in R.  The scant documentation contains the following cryptic passage:

> Put caret on a word that indicate dataframe or matrix, and `M-x
>   ess-R-dv-ctable` or `M-x ess-R-dv-pprint`. So, it popups other buffer
>   containing table.

I have the following packages installed:

- ctable
- ess
- ess-R-data-view
- popup

Additionally, I have R installed and have been able to use ESS without any problems.  I am running GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) (that is, Emacs on Windows).  I do not have Cygwin installed at this time.

Here is a link to the ess-R-data-view.el github:
https://github.com/myuhe/ess-R-data-view.el/blob/master/README.org

Comment: I would guess that they meant "cursor" instead of "caret".

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Yes! That is exactly what it means.  Putting my cursor on the data object and then entering `M-x ess-R-dv-ctable` loads the data frame in a separate window.

Comment: Cool. Glad that was it, because otherwise, I'd have had no clue!

Comment: [WordWeb online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=caret): "Noun: caret  ker-ut [N. Amer], ka-rut [Brit]
A mark used by an author or editor to indicate where something is to be inserted into a text"